# Are these JS conditional statements functionally equivalent?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Regarding conditional if/else statements, are the following examples functionally equivalent?

```
function isEntering() {
    if (this.stage === 'entering') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function isEntering() {
    if (this.stage === 'entering') {
        return true;
    } return false;
}

function isEntering() {
    if (this.stage === 'entering') {
        return true;
    } 
}

isEntering = (this.stage === 'entering') ? true : false;
```

If so, I'd use the most terse of the options. But only if the four are functionally equivalent.

Comment: `isEntering = (this.stage === 'entering')`

Comment: You omitted `isEntering = () => this.stage === 'entering';`.

Comment: this one `function isEntering() {
    if (this.stage === 'entering') {
        return true;
    } 
}` returns undefined in the case the others would return false, the others are equal

Comment: I added in the missing bracket in example 1. So now all four are equivalent?

Comment: The answer is yes except for the third one which returns `undefined` instead of false. Use PM 77-1's comment.

Comment: One, two and four are equivalent; three, however is not. By default, functions return undefined. Per the spec, the only value that `undefined` is coercively equal to is itself and `null`. So, it does not `==` or `===` `false`.

Comment: @mhodges no, four is **not** equivalent. Look more closely.

Comment: @torazaburo why? because it is not a function?

Comment: @epascarello Right. It sets a variable to the result of the comparison, rather than defining a function which returns the result of comparison.

Comment: @torazaburo **"Regarding conditional if/else statements, are the following examples functionally equivalent?"** It says nothing about functions. In terms of the conditionals, one, two, and four are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `expr` is a boolean expression, as it is here, then there is no need to write

```
if (expr) return true;
else return false;
```

or to write

```
if (expr) x = true;
else x = false;
```

or to ever write

```
expr ? true : false
```

because being a boolean expression, `expr` can be returned, or assigned, directly:

```
return expr;

x = expr;
```

The tersest alternative is one you didn't give:

```
function isEntering() { return this.stage === 'entering'; }
```

Comment: And in es6 fat-arrow syntax, this would be:
isEntering = () => { return this.stage === 'entering';  };

Answer (score 1):

They are not all equivalent.
The first two are equivalent, but:

```
function isEntering() {
    if (this.stage === 'entering') {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Would return `undefined` if `this.stage !== 'entering'`.

Also:

```
isEntering = (this.stage === 'entering') ? true : false;
```

Is not defining a function as the other examples.

As mentioned you can add:

```
isEntering = () => this.stage === 'entering';
```

If you don't need a function you can use:

```
isEntering = this.stage === 'entering'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was trying to ascertain. So it won't return "false" unless you explicitly include that as a condition. So it would still be "falsey", and evaluate to "false", but not actually completely functionally equivalent.

Comment: No, the last one is **not** equivalent. It sets the variable `isEntering`, instead of defining a function by that name.

Comment: @torazaburo is right, the last one is not equivalent, I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks. So, when needing a function, this is the most terse:
isEntering = () => this.stage === 'entering';