# Checking for Boolean Values in Typescript/Javascript Pertaining to "true", "false", and "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, boolean

What's an explicit way that I can be sure that the only results for a boolean check will be "true" or "false"? In other words, I want to exclude "undefined" as a possibility as much as is possible. Two options would be:

FUNCTION ONE:

```
private canMove = (currentOptionSelected): boolean => {
    if (this.client.services) {
        for (const service of this.client.services) {
            if (service === currentOptionSelected) {
                if (service.currentStage === 'enrolling') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

FUNCTION TWO:

```
private canMove = (currentOptionSelected): boolean => {
    if (this.client.services) {
        for (const service of this.client.services) {
            if (service === currentOptionSelected) {
                return service.currentStage === 'enrolling';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Upon a commenter's response, a more robust alternative is to explicitly return 'false', like this:

```
private canMove = (currentOptionSelected): boolean => {
    if (this.client.services) {
        for (const service of this.client.services) {
            if (service === currentOptionSelected) {
                //You should also rethink this return statement
                return service.currentStage === 'enrolling';
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would follow that up by asking if adding an extra "return 'false'" for a case where "client.services" exists, but "currentStage !== 'enrolling" would be even better? Or would that second 'else' clause be redundant in this case?

Secondly, he writes I should rethink the return statement in terms of where it is in the function. What would the alternative be? In short, I'm trying to find the most robust yet terse way to write this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are these JS conditional statements functionally equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830141/are-these-js-conditional-statements-functionally-equivalent)

Comment: The first will return `true` or `undefined`, the second `true`, `false` or `undefined`.

Comment: The first will return a value as soon as `service === currentOptionSelected` is `true`, while the second will continue to iterate over the remaining elements if the inner `if` statement is `false`.

Comment: I'm asking a more nuanced question here. In the previous question I did NOT include the second of these options. So it's not the same question. I'm specifically trying to clarify when "false" is returned as the only alternative to "true", rather than getting "true", "false", or "undefined". In other words, I want to avoid "undefined" as a possibility.

Comment: All these questions have been already answered.

Comment: I edited my question, and I think it's now clear I'm asking a different question. If you disagree, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

These are not equivalent. The second version returns `false` in some of the cases where the first one returns `undefined`. A caller that checks the value to be explicitly `=== false` will observe different behavior.

Both can return `undefined` which is probably not great. It'd be best to always return with an actual value of `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **No**, they aren't equivalent:

- The first one won't return `false` in any case.
- While the second can return `false` if `service.currentStage !== 'enrolling'`.

But as stated by Ryan both can return `undefined` which you should avoid, you need to explicitly return `false` whenever a condition isn't met.

This is how should be your code:

```
private canMove = (currentOptionSelected): boolean => {
    if (this.client.services) {
        for (const service of this.client.services) {
            if (service === currentOptionSelected) {
                //You should also rethink this return statement
                return service.currentStage === 'enrolling';
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Note:**

- The `return false;` here will make sure you return `false` when
  `this.client.services` is `undefined`.
- Using a `return` statement in a `for` loop this way is a very very bad idea, in fact you will only make one iteration.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying the way you've written the function above is a robust solution? Would adding an extra "return 'false'" for a case where "client.services" exists, but "currentStage !== 'enrolling" be even better? Or would that second 'else' clause be redundant in this case?

Comment: Also, if you're advising against using the return statement the way I am, what would you suggest as an alternative? What's a robust way to write this function?

Comment: @Ademo No if `currentStage !== 'enrolling"` `false` will be automatically returned, but what I was talking about is that the function will have only one iteration because you are returning in the loop, so it will always quit the function with that `return` in the first iteration. But can you just tell me why are you using it this way, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So this is being used in an Angular app. And I have this set up so that this function runs every time the user makes a new "currentOptionSelected" choice. So in that sense, running once through the iteration each time should be sufficient.

Comment: It won't iterate over `services`, just the first service and quits. If that is sufficient for you then go with it.